# This flow can't reference $Record because its trigger type is null

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-flow-builder

Am trying to deploy my flow, am getting below error. Could you anyone please let me know if anyone faced this issue.

> This flow can't reference $Record because its trigger type is null. Change the trigger type, change the flow global variable, or remove the flow global variable from this flow.

Comment: Hi @Anusha, Can you confirm the API version of the flow. I hope we have some issue with API version 46.

Comment: Iam using version 50.